# c# foreach not getting next XElement name in loop

Tags: c#, sql, xml

I have the following code that is supposed to do the following:

If there are records returned in xml format from a webservice, loop through each record, get the ErrorCode, ErrorMessage, and ID.  Email that information.  Then parse out each record and write the child elements to a table.  The problem is that it is writing the same record as many times as the number of records.  I can't seem to figure out why.  The email portion works as expected.

Here's the code:

```
#region If There Are RecordsInError From Broker Acknowledgement
if (srca.NumberOfResponseRecordsInError != "0")
{
    int TotalCount ;
    int.TryParse(srca.NumberOfResponseRecordsInError,out TotalCount);
    string[] ErrorCode = new string[TotalCount];
    string[] ErrorMessage = new string[TotalCount];
    string EmailBody = null;
    string StateRequestRecordGUID = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < TotalCount; i++)
    {
        //ZJR: Populate the string arrays with Error
        ErrorCode[i] = srca.FailedSeparationResponse[i].ErrorOccurrence[0].ErrorCode;
        ErrorMessage[i] = srca.FailedSeparationResponse[i].ErrorOccurrence[0].ErrorMessage;
        StateRequestRecordGUID = srca.FailedSeparationResponse[i].StateRequestRecordGUID;

        //ZJR: Database connection to insert Error Records
        SqlConnection conn4 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=test_BdbCSSQL01;Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        conn4.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM ERROROfSIDESStagingOUT";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn4);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        DataRow dr;
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XmlString.xml");
        XNamespace ns = "https://uidataexchange.org/schemas";

        var node = doc.Descendants(ns + "EmployerTPASeparationResponse");

        using (da)
        {
            foreach (var param in node.Elements())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (dr.Table.Columns.Contains(param.Name.LocalName))
                    {
                        dr[param.Name.LocalName] = param.Value;
                    }
                    //param.NextNode;
                }
                catch (Exception ee)
                {
                    string asdf = ee.ToString();
                }
            }
            SqlCommandBuilder sb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            da.Update(dt);
        }

        if (conn4 != null)
        {
            conn4.Close();
        }

        //ZJR: Build the Email Body
        EmailBody = EmailBody + "StateRequestRecordGUID: " + StateRequestRecordGUID + Environment.NewLine + "ErrorCode: " + ErrorCode[i] + " : " + ErrorMessage[i] + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
        SendEmail mail = new SendEmail();
        mail.Send(EmailBody, "Sides Error Event");
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: @Oscar: did you actually edit anything?

Comment: It seems like @Joce reformated the code a few seconds before I did, so it got overwritten `:)`. The code had unnecessary spaces at the begining of each and it makes it less readable.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  It was the using (da) line.  I got rid of that and the code works great.